# Combining columns within the same df Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to the programming world and can't figure out how to concatenate columns in `pandas`. I'm not looking to join these columns, but rather stack them on top of each other.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Kit Wesselhoeft\\Documents\\NEM\\Northend Manufacturing_deletecol.xlsx")

print(df)

df = pd.concat(['A','A'])

print(df)
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTOl1.png)

I want to combine all the columns so that all the A's sit on top of each other, Same with the B's - E's.

How can I do this?  Am I missing something?

Comment: If possible can you include a brief example of what the data looks like in your question?  Linking to outside images is not ideal.  Having the text in the question let's people copy and paste the content to work with it on their own to come up with a solution.  It also makes it easier for people reading your question to understand what you're asking and what your desired output is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain column ordering is consistent and tiled [A,B,C,A,B,C...], then you can create a new `DataFrame` by reshaping the old. Otherwise safer alternatives exist with `pd.wide_to_long` which uses the actual column names.

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 15)),
                  columns=list('BACDE')*3)
#   B  A  C  D  E  B  A  C  D  E  B  A  C  D  E
#0  3  3  7  2  4  7  2  1  2  1  1  4  5  1  1
#1  5  2  8  4  3  5  8  3  5  9  1  8  4  5  7
#2  2  6  7  3  2  9  4  6  1  3  7  3  5  5  7
```

#### Reshape

```
cols = pd.unique(df.columns)  # Preserves Order
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, len(cols)), columns=cols)
#   B  A  C  D  E
#0  3  3  7  2  4
#1  7  2  1  2  1
#2  1  4  5  1  1
#3  5  2  8  4  3
#4  5  8  3  5  9
#5  1  8  4  5  7
#6  2  6  7  3  2
#7  9  4  6  1  3
#8  7  3  5  5  7
```

#### `pd.wide_to_long`

Useful when your columns are not in the same tiling order, or if you have more of some than others. Requires you to modify the column names by adding `_N` for which occurrence of the column it is.

```
cols = pd.unique(df.columns)
s = pd.Series(df.columns).groupby(df.columns).cumcount()
df.columns = [f'{col}_{N}' for col,N in zip(df.columns, s)]

pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=cols, i='index', j='num', sep='_').reset_index(drop=True)
#   B  A  C  D  E
#0  3  3  7  2  4
#1  5  2  8  4  3
#2  2  6  7  3  2
#3  7  2  1  2  1
#4  5  8  3  5  9
#5  9  4  6  1  3
#6  1  4  5  1  1
#7  1  8  4  5  7
#8  7  3  5  5  7
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Sorry for the novis question, but this is a huge help

Comment: @quadle it’s a fine question. Just next time try to include sample data, instead of an image, as I have, to make it easy to reproduce your problem. People are much more likely to answer when they can simply copy and paste to start solving :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all your help! I'll be sure to include sample data moving forward. Just my second post, and still a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for "append":

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, (3,2)),columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, (3,2)),columns=list('AB'))
df3=df.append(df2)

In [2]: df3
Out[2]: 
   A  B
0  7  6
1  8  3
2  2  1
0  2  2
1  1  3
2  5  5
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example is relevant when you exactly know where your columns are. Building on [ALollz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz) code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 15)),
                  columns=list('BACDE')*3)
#   B  A  C  D  E  B  A  C  D  E  B  A  C  D  E
#0  3  3  7  2  4  7  2  1  2  1  1  4  5  1  1
#1  5  2  8  4  3  5  8  3  5  9  1  8  4  5  7
#2  2  6  7  3  2  9  4  6  1  3  7  3  5  5  7

# Using iloc

df1 = df.iloc[:, :5]

df2 = df.iloc[:,5:10]

df3 = df.iloc[:,10:]

df_final= pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result `df_final`:

```
    B   A   C   D   E

0   3   3   7   2   4
1   5   2   8   4   3
2   2   6   7   3   2
3   7   2   1   2   1
4   5   8   3   5   9
5   9   4   6   1   3
6   1   4   5   1   1
7   1   8   4   5   7
8   7   3   5   5   7
```