# Appending / Creating new df w/ for loops

Tags: python, pandas

You guys helped me out so much yesterday, and I was able to get the task done in py and not excel. However, the code I wrote is absolute trash.

100 columns. A:A.19, B:B:19 - all the way to E:E.19.

I wanted to append all the A's to one column all the way to the E's.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import xlsxwriter


df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NEM\\Northend 
Manufacturing_deletecol2.xlsx")

df = df.rename(columns={'A.1': 'A', 'A.2': 'A','A.3': 'A','A.4': 'A', 'A.5': 
                    'A','A.6': 'A','A.7': 'A', 'A.8': 'A','A.9': 'A','A.10': 
                    'A', 'A.11': 'A','A.12': 'A','A.13': 'A', 'A.14': 
                    'A','A.15': 'A','A.16': 'A', 'A.17': 'A','A.18': 
                    'A','A.19': 'a', 
                    'B.1': 'B', 'B.2': 'B','B.3': 'B','B.4': 'B', 'B.5': 
                    'B','B.6': 'B','B.7': 'B', 'B.8': 'B','B.9': 'B','B.10': 
                    'B', 'B.11': 'B','B.12': 'B','B.13': 'B', 'B.14': 
                    'B','B.15': 'B','B.16': 'B', 'B.17': 'B','B.18': 
                    'B','B.19': 'B',
                    'C.1': 'C', 'C.2': 'C','C.3': 'C','C.4': 'C', 'C.5': 
                    'C','C.6': 'C','C.7': 'C', 'C.8': 'C','C.9': 'C','C.10': 
                    'C', 'C.11': 'C','C.12': 'C','C.13': 'C', 'C.14': 
                    'C','C.15': 'C','C.16': 'C', 'C.17': 'C','C.18': 
                    'C','C.19': 'C',
                    'D.1': 'D', 'D.2': 'D','D.3': 'D','D.4': 'D', 'D.5': 
                    'D','D.6': 'D','D.7': 'D', 'D.8': 'D','D.9': 'D','D.10': 
                    'D', 'D.11': 'D','D.12': 'D','D.13': 'D', 'D.14': 
                    'D','D.15': 'D','D.16': 'D', 'D.17': 'D','D.18': 
                    'D','D.19': 'D',
                    'E.1': 'E', 'E.2': 'E','E.3': 'E','E.4': 'E', 'E.5': 
                    'E','E.6': 'E','E.7': 'E', 'E.8': 'E','E.9': 'E','E.10': 
                    'E', 'E.11': 'E','E.12': 'E','E.13': 'E', 'E.14': 
                    'E','E.15': 'E','E.16': 'E', 'E.17': 'E','E.18': 
                    'E','E.19': 'E'})

df1 = df.iloc[:, :5]
df2 = df.iloc[:,5:10]
df3 = df.iloc[:,10:15]
df4 = df.iloc[:,15:20]
df5 = df.iloc[:,20:25]
df6 = df.iloc[:,25:30]
df7 = df.iloc[:,30:35]
df8 = df.iloc[:,35:40]
df9 = df.iloc[:,40:45]
df10 = df.iloc[:,45:50]
df11 = df.iloc[:,50:55]
df12 = df.iloc[:,55:60]
df13 = df.iloc[:,60:65]
df14 = df.iloc[:,65:70]
df15 = df.iloc[:,70:75]
df16 = df.iloc[:,75:80]
df17 = df.iloc[:,80:85]
df18 = df.iloc[:,85:90]
df19 = df.iloc[:,90:95]
df20 = df.iloc[:,95:99]

df_final= pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,

df11,df12,df13,df14,df15,df16,df17,df18,df19,df20]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_final)
```

This worked however I feel like a doofus and know there is a way to loop through this problem instead of calling out each dataframe to draw the first 5 variable.

Any thoughts on how to make this better?

Comment: Instead of using all those different variables, work the indexing e.g.`[:,50:55]` into variables that increment with a for loop and then save that `df.iloc` into a part of a list rather than its own variable.

Comment: Your initial columns are in the perfect form for this to work with my [second solution using pd.wide_to_long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751715/4333359). Don't rename, change the separator to `sep='.'` and just define the stubs as `pd.unique([x.split('.')[0] for x in df.columns])`. Then use that one line code of `pd.wide_to_long`

Comment: Also, if you want to save yourself some typing, that entire dictionary can be created with: `dict((f'{char}.{num}', char) for char in list('ABCDE') for num in range(1,20))`

Comment: Thanks @aLollz i was not able to get the pd.wide_to_long function to work yesterday. I was able to get the data set out to a client "i work as a data analyst for a very small start up." Now that I have some time I'll go ahead and test it out. Appreciate it!